# Getting a NameError: uninitialized constant error upgrading to Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm getting this error

```
Overwrite /my_app/bin/setup? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdhm] n
        skip  bin/setup
       rails  active_storage:update
rails aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Mappings

  include Mappings::Model
          ^^^^^^^^
/my_app/config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb:17:in `block in <main>'
/my_app/config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb:16:in `<main>'
/my_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => active_storage:update => environment
```

while running `bin/rails app:update` to move from Rails 6.1 to Rails 7

The error is being caused by

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  include Mappings::Model
end
```

I tried adding require and the file name at the top of `wrap_parameters` and that's not working.

Answer (score 5):

Rails 6 issued warnings for this situation. Autoloading from initializers was deprecated, and the feature removed in Rails 7.

This is unrelated to Zeitwerk, autoloading from initializers was just wrong conceptually regardless of the autoloader.

Please see [this section](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-when-the-application-boots) of the autoloading guide.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly a zeitwerk compatibility problem, since it's now the default in Rails 7.

What it means is that the `Mappings::Model` class can't be found b/c it's not in the file structure that zeitwerk expects.

Suggest you start by running the zeitwerk check from the command line: `bin/rails zeitwerk:check`. It should find the problem for you and lead you to a solution.

If `zeitwerk:check` doesn't find any problems, then check the [zeitwerk guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/classic_to_zeitwerk_howto.html) and then use the correct, zeitwerk-compliant, file name and location for the file containing the `Mappings::Model` class.

Probably can be fixed by putting the `Mappings::Model` class in app/models/mappings/model.rb

Comment: zeitwerk:check is giving me the same error as above, not really showing me how to correct it though

Comment: ok I added a suggestion to my answer

Comment: FYI, based on the error I'd say it's going to be the `Mappings` module, not the `Model` one.